# Haskell return lazy string from file IO

Tags: haskell, file-io, lazy-evaluation

Here I'm back again with a (for me) really strange behaviour of my newest masterpiece...

This code should read a file, but it doesn't:

```
readCsvContents :: String -> IO ( String )
readCsvContents fileName = do
     withFile fileName ReadMode (\handle -> do
          contents <- hGetContents handle
          return contents
          )

main = do
    contents <- readCsvContents "src\\EURUSD60.csv"
    putStrLn ("Read " ++ show (length contents) ++ " Bytes input data.")
```

The result is

```
Read 0 Bytes input data.
```

Now I changed the first function and added a `putStrLn`:

```
readCsvContents :: String -> IO ( String )
readCsvContents fileName = do
     withFile fileName ReadMode (\handle -> do
          contents <- hGetContents handle
          putStrLn ("hGetContents gave " ++ show (length contents) ++ " Bytes of input data.")
          return contents
          )
```

and the result is

```
hGetContents gave 3479360 Bytes of input data.
Read 3479360 Bytes input data.
```

WTF ??? Well, I know, Haskell is lazy. But I didn't know I had to kick it in the butt like this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're right, this is a pain. Avoid using the old standard file IO module, for this reason – except to simply read an entire file that won't change, as you did; this can be done just fine with `readFile`.

```
readCsvContents :: Filepath -> IO String
readCsvContents fileName = do
   contents <- readFile fileName
   return contents
```

Note that, by the monad laws, this is exactly the same<sup>1</sup> as

```
readCsvContents = readFile
```

The problem with what you tried is that the handle is closed unconditionally when the monad exits `withFile`, without checking whether lazy-evaluation of `contents` has actually forced the file reads. That is of course horrible; I would never bother to use handles myself. `readFile` avoids the problem by linking the closing of the handle to garbage-collection of the original result thunk; this isn't altogether nice either but often works quite well.

For proper work with file IO, check out either the [conduit](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/conduit) or [pipes](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/pipes) library. The former focuses a bit more on performance, the latter more on elegance (but really, the difference isn't that big).

---

<sup>1</sup><sub>And your first try is the same as `readCsvContents fn = withFile fn ReadMode hGetContents`.</sub>

Answer (score 3):

This is a problem with lazy IO. What happens in your code is that `withFile` opens the file, passes the handle to the lambda. This lambda returns a lazy list containing the contents of the file. Then `withFile` notices that the callback finished and closes the file.

Since the returned list is lazy, the file contents will only be read when the list is evaluated. This happens in the call to `length`. However, at this point the file handle is already closed and therefore you can't read anything from the file.

The modified version of your call forces the file contents in the `withFile` argument, at which point the file is still available, and therefore it works.